# each loop for insertafter failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add `<span class='validation'></span>` after each `<label class="control-label">`. I have tried following but it's adding span class multiple times after each label.

I have also tried using `.one()` after control label class but didn't worked.

I want to add same class for each select as well. will adding select inside `$('#myform :input')` work?

what is wrong in this code.

```
$('#myform :input').each(function(){
    $( "<span class='validation'></span>").insertAfter(".control-label");                           
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
     <label for="Rec_Name" class="control-label">Your Name :</label>    
     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Rec_Name" name="Rec_Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you add span to after each control-label class.

Try like this:

```
$('<span>Validation</span>').insertAfter($(this).parent().find('.control-label'));
```

Maybe a little crazy but should work.
Hope this helps.

Comment: $(this) will be the input, not the label

Comment: Yep..need to adjust answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mykola. your answer worked. Big thanks to you :-)

Comment: Np.Glad to help. Check @Amincharoliya answer it's Ok too.

Answer (score 1):

You can target `.control-label`.

Example:

HTML

```
<form action="">
    <label for="Rec_Name" class="control-label">Your Name :</label>    
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Rec_Name" name="Rec_Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$('form .control-label').each(function(){
    $( "<span class='validation'></span>").insertAfter(this);
});
```

Comment: Yep i like it better.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply

```
$("<span class='validation'></span>").insertBefore("#myform .control-label+:input");
```

this will insert a span between anything with class `control-label` immediately followed by an `:input`

this precisely targets what you were intending to do in your question