# weird jquery & css behavior in localhost Vs live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179762/each-loop-for-insertafter-failing) i asked today & got resolved. I am seeing a weird jquery & css behavior in localhost Vs live server. Attaching 2 images here to understand the issue correctly.

**Jquery behavior** : working fine when used in localhost in terms of outside border (red, green), icon placement as desired but in live server it's behaving in different manner (icon placed wrongly inside select, red,green border not showing).

**CSS behavior** : Check bootstrap select placeholder font in both (live vs localhost). localhost is producing actual color what it should do but live server is fading the color.

My first doubt was, since I am using fallback.io script for file loading, there could be error in server file sequence but everything is same as localhost. I am not able to find out what is causing this issue.

if may want to check live server at [Live server link](http://vacancycalling.com/Employers/registration.php)

**EDIT**

js code I am using to create error classes for outside border & icon. These are working fine in localhost but behaving differently in server.

```
$('.selectpicker').on('keyup keypress blur change click', function(){
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
        alert($(this).parent());
        $(this).parent().find('span:first').removeClass('valid').addClass('error').focus(); 
        $(this).parent().find('.bootstrap-select').removeClass('formvalid').addClass('formerror');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().find('span:first').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
        $(this).parent().find('.bootstrap-select').removeClass('formerror').addClass('formvalid');
    }
}); 

$('.selectpicker').on('show.bs.select', function () {   
    //set red border by default whether selection done or not
    $(this).parent().find('.bootstrap-select').removeClass('formvalid').addClass('formerror');

    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
        $(this).parent().find('span:first').removeClass('valid').addClass('error').focus();
        $(this).parent().find('.bootstrap-select').removeClass('formvalid').addClass('formerror');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().find('span:first').removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
        $(this).parent().find('.bootstrap-select').removeClass('formerror').addClass('formvalid');
    }
});
```

**2nd EDIT 28-AUG-2016**

Though CSS is behaving differently but Jquery code should work as desired because span class is already created above select box which we are modifying using below code that can be seen in top right of image (yellow & blue highlighted area). this is another issue where class `error` should be added in span element having class `Validation` but is place of traversing to parent, it's moving towards children. attaching image for jquery error with explanation.
[image]

1) icon placement in localhost Vs live Server [image: (image 1)]

2) file sequence in localhost Vs live server [image: (image 2)]

Comment: are you sure the css and js files listed in your live server environment actually exist and are the same versions as the ones you're calling from localhost?  looks like you may be missing including some crucial css or js on the server; i'd check errors in console to ensure all files are loaded, then doublecheck that code versions are the same.

Comment: @derelict yes, i have checked this as my first doubt that's why i transferred all my files which were modified recently to live server. actually there were two scripts which were modified (new-style.css & forms.js). forms.js was newly created after getting answer from first question i mentioned in the link.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console? I guess at least one of your resources didn't load correctly.

Comment: @Dekel i have modified the all scripts once again. But no luck. all scripts are loaded correctly as they exists in localhost. I have edited my question (2nd edit) which is causing jquery weird behavior. Though i am not much concerned with css behavior but still error is error & should be solved.